# Дэбаггер в VS code

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code, отладка

По видео-туториалам, заполнил `.json` файлы, но столкнулся с проблемой, что дебаггер, вроде как, запускается, но долго грузится.

Вот файлы:

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "my_debug",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGw\\bin\\g++.exe",
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "main.cpp",
                "-o",
                "main.exe"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe сборка активного файла",
            "command": "C:\\MinGw\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "компилятор: C:\\MinGw\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Когда я нажимаю `F5`, в консоли отладчика появляется следующее:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\Прога\C++>  & 'c:\Users\User\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.18.5-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-z2nobhl0.e10' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-vqnbvhko.pu5' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-emwwfh13.djk' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-wechwab5.dgm' '--dbgExe=C:\MinGw\bin\g++.exe' '--interpreter=mi'
```

(хотелось бы узнать, что это он мне такое выводит)

А потом у меня появляются часы рядом со значком дебаггера - и ничего больше не происходит.

[image: Значок дебаггера с часами]

Также после такого как в консоли нажму комбинацию `Ctrl + C` у меня вылетает следующее:

[image: Всплывающее окно "unable to start debugging"]

В чем ошибка? Что я не так сделал и как это исправить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66365840/debug-with-f5-fails-on-vscode-saying-unable-to-establish-a-connection-to-gdb

Comment: @Глеб нее, это я уже смотрел, с этим у меня вообще ничего не запускается(

Comment: `"miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGw\\bin\\g++.exe"` - компилятор почему-то указан в качестве отладчика

Comment: @BogdanWitcher, тебе уже сказали что у тебя компилятор указан вместо отладчика `gdb`.

Comment: @evo, да, я увидел, но я поменял, у меня он запускаться перестал, начал мне выдавать заполнять workspace.json, я и его заполнил, но так ничего и не заработало